# How can a Solana Rust smart contract get block height or Unix time?

Tags: solana-program, rust

I know how to pass the current Unix time from the frontend:

web3.js:

```
anchor.web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY
```

Rust:

```
let current_time = ctx.accounts.clock.unix_timestamp;
```

I do not want that. I need the smart contract itself to get the current time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using anchor

```
let now_ts = Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp;
```

You will need to pass in the system program account

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean when you say "smart contract itself to get the current time"?

```
#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let clock = Clock::get().unwrap();
        msg!("Timestamp: {}!", clock.unix_timestamp); // Message will show up in the tx logs
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {}
```

The program log will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you have above is how the smart contract "itself" gets the current time.

When you add `anchor.web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY` to your accounts, you're not passing in time from the frontend. You're simply specifying the public key of a `system account` that stores a cluster of on-chain data relating to time on Solana.

That account is verified by the`clock: Sysvar<Clock, 'info>` line in your validator and is the authority on handling time in Solana.

Answer (score 0):

```
// pass this to Context
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreatePost<'info> {
    // add other properties
    pub post: Account<'info, PostAccount>,
    // Clock to save time of post
    pub clock: Sysvar<'info, Clock>,
}
```

PostAccount struct:

```
#[account]
pub struct PostAccount {
    // add other properties

    // post time
    pub post_time: i64,
}
```

Define function in `mod`

```
pub fn create_post(ctx: Context<CreatePost>) -> ProgramResult {
     let post = &mut ctx.accounts.post;
     // get the timestamp of post
     post.post_time = ctx.accounts.clock.unix_timestamp;

 }
```